# Crystal Reports - Get First, Second and Third occurrence of linkedTable value

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following One-To-Many scenario:

One Record -> To -> Many Notes (of types X, Y and Z)

In the page for each Record, I need to include only the first 3 Notes of Type X in chronological order.

How do I do this? I've tried setting 3 subreports, but I can't tell the second and third subreport which notes have already been selected as part of the prior occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an extension to your solution.

1. First select only select 3 records to be retrieved from database.
2. Now sort either ascending or descending order in all 3 sub reports.
3. Now in sub report 1 suppress 2 and 3 records in the same way in second sub report suppress 1 and 3 records and in sub report 3 suppress 1 and 2 records.

You can suppress the records by placing the special field `Record Number` and suppress condition would be

```
if recordnumber = 1
then true
else false
```

Same way for second and third records.

Comment: I love how simple this solution is - especially considering non-Technical people may need to update the report in the future. This answer works very well. Shawnt has a point about performance, especially considering I haven't found an way way to make crystal implement with (nolock), limit, offset or range. In my case, it actually allowed me to remove references top a low performance table (notes) and be more selective in how the sub reports select records. I would recommend any user with an issue similar to mine consider performance and choose the solution best suited to their environment and

Answer (score 1):

```
{@ResetCounter} // Place this in the group/page header where you want to restart the counter
global numbervar counter := 0;

Place this in the section suppression formula
global numbervar counter;
counter := counter + 1;
counter > 3; // if true then suppress
```

If you have multiple sections to suppress make sure you only increment one time. So just remove the middle line in the subsequent suppression formulas.

Comment: This answer works as a solution, but may prove difficult in the future if a non-technical person needs to update the Report. Both your reply and Siva's have been tested as working solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Having three subreports will require the query to run three times per group. It could become incredibly slow depending on the nature of your report over just pulling back all the data at once.

Comment: Good point, and true. One of many reasons I wish I could use limit, offset or range in reports. I tested both methods, but the other allowed me to remove the notes table from the main report entirely while being more selective in pulling data from that (huge) table. I feel lucky to have received 2 very applicable answers. I wish I could mark both as such :-)

Comment: I'm fine if my answer is not chosen. Fetching only three rows inside the subreport makes sense. You might look at `cross apply` if you're on SQL Server.